# What does this 'extend' mean here?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, error

I found a bio of a professor and it has a sentence as below

> Not totally satisfied with the extend and nature of understanding of biological phenomena I could reach via pure experimental approaches, I moved on and turned to ...

I'm not sure what the 'extend' here means, which is a noun. I checked in the Webster dictionary and it does not have a noun form of this word.

For your reference, here is the [bio](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/biography.html). I hope I don't infringe privacy putting the link here.

Comment: It's a typo of "extent".

Comment: @CowperKettle Er, this explanation makes sense, but ...

Comment: I agree with CowperKettle

Comment: It's a common and quite harmless typo. I met a couple of similar typos in an industrial document I tried to translate some days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CowperKettle says, this is almost certainly a typo for "extent".

"Extend" is a verb. We do not normally put an article like "the" in front of a very. "I the ate breakfast"? No. Also "extend and nature" does not make sense. You can put a conjunction between two nouns, and you can put a conjunction between two verbs, but you can't put a conjunction between a verb and a noun.

But "extent" makes perfect sense in context.